# How to implement logging in blazor (Server side - 3.1)

Tags: blazor-server-side

How to implement logging in blazor

I’m using Blazor (3.1) Server approach

I want to log (to a file) some events

I have try this extension: https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Logging but I can’t make it to work as it says.

Can someone point me to a working example? Or Tell me if I’m doing something wrong (I’m getting this error with this approach:

A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Serilog

this implementation for server side
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/log-data-into-file-using-serilog-framework-in-blazor-server-app/

and this for client side
https://nblumhardt.com/2019/11/serilog-blazor/

also you will need to read
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 4):

In order to implement logging for Blazor server you would follow the same approach as you would for a [.NET Core or ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) application.

Namely in your Program.cs file you would need to modify the CreateHostBuilder method to configure your loggers in a manner such as

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

You could then inject an ILogger into your razor components or throughout the rest of your application using dependency injection.

```
public class AboutModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AboutModel(ILogger<AboutModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Message = $"About page visited at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()}";
        _logger.LogInformation(Message);
    }
}
```

Be sure to check the Microsoft documentation for information on [built in loggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#bilp), [third party loggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#third-party-logging-providers), and just [logging in general](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: in Blazor Server .net5 APP I do not know why ErrorModel class logs my LogError and another log message. How can I disable the default logger

Answer (score 2):

Right now, it appears that logging with Blazor.Extensions.Logging is not supported for Blazor Server-Side applications due to the circular dependency with IJSRuntime:

https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Logging/issues/44

PHeuter: "IJSRuntime may need to log and the logger needs IJSRuntime to do the logging."